# x~y[==""] - Comparing Groups Divided by Grouping Variables

Tags: r, variables, grouping

I'm still getting my head around some of the R syntax and wanted to inquire on how to efficiently perform the following analysis, without having to change my whole dataframe from long to wide etc.

This is my dataframe:

```
> data.frame(SOExample)
    StudyID TimePoint   Group      Conc
1  N0920235        BL Control 0.7998743
2  N1020555        BL Control 0.3839061
3  N1020621        BL Control 0.5446354
4  N1121951        BL Control 0.5146689
5  N1122107        BL Control 0.5431685
6  N1122225        BL Control 0.5775356
7  N1122221        BL Control 0.9474015
8  N1222611        BL Control 0.6194468
9  N1222745        BL Control 0.7110226
10 N1222781        BL Control 0.5347863
11 N1223363        BL Control 0.5079631
12 N1223541        BL Control 0.5054484
13 N1223579        BL Control 0.8162196
14 N1122171        BL Control 0.4997904
15 N0920198        BL Control 0.5924141
16 N0920367        BL Control 0.6244761
17 N1021085        BL Control 0.7759849
18 N1121329        BL Control 0.3845348
19 N1121389        BL Control 1.1695306
20 N1121475        BL Control 1.7254820
21 N1121871        BL Control 0.7080889
22 N1121875        BL Control 0.8214585
23 N1122021        BL Control 0.7384744
24 N1122103        BL Control 0.6026823
25 N1122283        BL Control 0.7581727
26 N1122321        BL Control 0.5282900
27 N1222493        BL Control 0.4258173
28 N1222529        BL Control 0.1538139
29 N1222587        BL Control 0.7663453
30 N1222705        BL Control 0.5873847
31 N1222693        BL Control 0.6584241
32 N1222761        BL Control 0.3321459
33   MP0001        BL Patient 0.8216681
34   MP0002        BL Patient 0.4800922
35   MP0007        BL Patient 0.8822297
36   MP0008        BL Patient 0.8975272
37   MP0010        BL Patient 0.7567058
38   MP0011        BL Patient 0.4893127
39   MP0017        BL Patient 0.5840319
40   MP0022        BL Patient 0.8053227
41   MP0023        BL Patient 0.7837370
42   MP0024        BL Patient 0.3938870
43   MP0027        BL Patient 0.6345636
44   MP0028        BL Patient 0.6234141
45   MP0029        BL Patient 0.7101115
46   MP0001        3M Patient 0.5415225
47   MP0002        3M Patient 0.3986928
48   MP0007        3M Patient 0.5722799
49   MP0008        3M Patient 0.5140331
50   MP0010        3M Patient 0.4913495
51   MP0011        3M Patient 0.5288351
52   MP0017        3M Patient 0.2931565
53   MP0023        3M Patient 0.2149173
54   MP0024        3M Patient 0.3794694
55   MP0028        3M Patient 0.6322568
56   MP0029        3M Patient 0.5297962
```

So what I'd like to do is something really, really simple. Compare Patients vs. Controls at the TimePoint "BL". But for some reason, R won't except my code:

```
t.test(Conc~Group[TimePoint=="BL"], data=SOExample)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Conc ~ Group[TimePoint == "BL"],  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Group[TimePoint == "BL"]')
```

Now further down, I'd like to perform a `pairwise.t.test` to compare Patients at BL to Controls and Patients at 3M to Controls. I though, something like the following would've worked, but you'll see R doesn't like it:

```
> pairwise.t.test(SOExample$Conc~Group|TimePoint, data=SOExample)
Error in factor(g) : argument "g" is missing, with no default
```

So I've also tried the following:

```
> t.test(Conc~Group, data=SOExample[SOExample$TimePoint=="BL",])

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Conc by Group
t = -0.452, df = 36.94, p-value = 0.6539
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1638470  0.1040813
sample estimates:
mean in group Control mean in group Patient 
            0.6518559             0.6817387
```

But now, when I want to compare Patients at 3M versus Controls, I get this message:

```
> t.test(Conc~Group, data=SOExample[SOExample$TimePoint=="3M",])
Error in t.test.formula(Conc ~ Group, data = SOExample[SOExample$TimePoint ==  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

Any ideas? I can, of course, change my whole data format, but that's just a pain. I'd prefer not to have multiple text files for the same dataset.

Comment: The reason you're getting the second error, "grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels," is that your Group variable only takes value "Patient" at TimePoint value 3M. Is TimePoint a factor in your data frame?

Comment: You don't have any 3M controls, hence the error on levels, you gave it 1 level, Patients only.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, I know I don't have a 3M TimePoint in my controls. But I don't want that. I want to compare patients at 3 months follow up to healthy controls at BL...
@ josilber - yes, TimePoint is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking for, as the question wording is a bit confusing (to me), but here are some options:

All Patients vs. All Controls at TimePoint BL:

```
t.test(Conc~Group, data=SOExample[SOExample$TimePoint=="BL",])
```

All Patients at 3M vs. All Controls at BL:

```
with(SOExample,t.test(Conc[TimePoint=="BL" & Group=="Control"],
                      Conc[TimePoint=="3M" & Group=="Patient"]))
```

Pairwise Comparison of Patients at 3M to Patients at BL (paired based on Study ID):

```
ID.3M <- SOExample[SOExample$TimePoint=="3M",]$StudyID
df    <- SOExample[SOExample$StudyID %in% ID.3M,]
t.test(Conc~TimePoint, data=df, paired=T)
```

Comment: @ Thomas - Thanks for editing my question to help clarify aspects of it.

Comment: @ jihoward: You're a star. That's exactly what I needed. I didn't know about the "&" - makes total sense though now! Also the pairwise comparison is absolutely fantastic; didn't think of making a separate df to overcome the problem of different lengths. Excellent help guys. Thank's so much.